# what is the default Space size in JPOS and How to increase the default space size in JPOS?

Tags: jpos

I am using JPOS transaction manager for developement. I want to know the exact default space size in JPOS.How to increase it.what should i do for increasing it.

Comment: The jPOS Space uses as much memory as available for the JVM. In a properly configured system, the space use by the transaction manager is minimal, so I guess you have a memory leak of some sort here.

Comment: how to increase memory in the same case?